# Как работать с MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Скачал и установил MongoDB. Работаю через MongoDB Compass. Как я понял благодоря этой программе лазить в терминале нет необходимости. Так вот, мне необходимо с Telegram бота занести в базу все данные об пользователе. Но главный вопрос, как? Раньше работал с MySQL, там как известно все это делается через запросы. Но здесь? Вот как мне сюда добавить - username, chat.id и прочее?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю я с node js и библиотекой "mongoose". Весь день бьюсь об стенку с этим вопросом. Задаю анологичные вопросы с MySQL. Но ответы вообще не те. Я не знаю, как мне проавильно сформулировать запрос поиска. По возможности, дайте ссылки и примеры кода добавления и подключения;)

Answer (score 2):

Ну например:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// подключение
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/tgbot_test", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
...
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// установка схемы
const userScheme = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  chat_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  collection: 'users'
});
// создание модели
const User = mongoose.model("User", userScheme);
...

router.get('/', wrap(async function(req, res, next) {
  let query = User.find()
  const searchName = req.query.name
  if (searchName) {
    query = query.where('username').regex(new RegExp(`${searchName}`))
  }
  const foundUsers = await query.exec();
  res.json(foundUsers)
}));

router.post('/', wrap(async function(req, res, next) {
  const userProps = req.body
  const user = new User(userProps);
  try {
    const newUser = await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
}));

router.put('/:id', wrap(async function(req, res, next) {
  const userProps = req.body
  const userId = req.params.id
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).exec();
    user.set(userProps)
    await user.save()
    res.status(200).end();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
}));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но как то все сложно для меня пока что)

Comment: Пока не прогуляешься по докам монго и монгуса ничего само не придёт )) Я сам недавно только начал изучать это всё, до этого был опыт только с обычными SQL-driven базами. Начните с описания схемы, модели запросов чтобы получать объекты через модель